# Why does my $PATH grow every time I run source?

Tags: bash

I have noticed that every time I type:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

in my bash terminal, my $PATH variable keeps getting appended to.

Why is this, and how do I stop it from happening? I just want my current terminal to pick up any changes I have made to my `.bash_profile` file

Comment: Your profile presumably has something like `PATH=$PATH:stuff:to:add`.

Comment: Doen't it auto run on user login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put this in my profile

```
# This is in /etc/profile
pathmunge () {
    case ":${PATH}:" in
        *:"$1":*)
            ;;
        *)
            [ ! -d "$1" ] && return
            if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                PATH=$PATH:$1
            else
                PATH=$1:$PATH
            fi
    esac
}

pathmunge /some/nifty/dir before          # not: PATH=/some/nifty/dir:$PATH
pathmunge /a/less/interesting/dir after   # not: PATH=$PATH:/a/less/interesting/dir
```

That only adds stuff to the path if it's missing.

Comment: Why -1? This sounds perfectly reasonable. There could probably be some scope for optimization, but this answer looks correct.

Comment: SO has had a rash of unexplained downvotes for apparently less than technical reasons. Who knows. I largely attribute it to the age and maturity of those running around casting the downvotes without the integrity to explain why. Maybe it makes them feel more important. Phase of the moon? All we can do is set good examples.

Comment: Yeah it happens. You can't take it too seriously.